No hotkeys are assigned to the sculpt brush
Blender 4.3
In Sculpt Mode and Paint Mode, I assign hotkeys to brushes via the right-click menu. But when pressing these hotkeys, an error is displayed: Tool 'builtin_brush.Elastic Deform' not found for space 'VIEW_3D'
The only way to solve the problem is to remove all functions from this key in the Keymap

What Blender version are you using?

Blender 4.3 The brushes have errors.

A quick check shows that it works fine with no errors here. Suggest you report it as a bug since it's such a new version. Help > Report a Bug detailing the exact sequence to get the error.
